# Difference between io.StringIO and a string variable in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python.

Can anybody explain what's the difference between a string variable and  io.StringIO . In both we can save character.

e.g

String variable

```
k= 'RAVI'
```

io.stringIO

```
string_out = io.StringIO()
string_out.write('A sample string which we have to send to server as string data.')
string_out.getvalue()
```

If we print k or string_out.getvalue() both will print  the text

```
print(k)
print(string_out.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are similar because both `str` and `StringIO` represent strings, they just do it in different ways:

- `str`: Immutable
- `StringIO`: Mutable, file-like interface, which *stores* `str`s

A text-mode file handle (as produced by `open("somefile.txt")`) is also very similar to `StringIO` (both are "Text I/O"), with the latter allowing you to avoid using an actual file for file-like operations.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `io.StringIO()` to simulate files, since python is dynamic with variable types usually if you have something that accepts a file object you can also use `io.StringIO()` with it, meaning you can have a "file" in memory that you can control the contents of without actually writing any temporary files to disk